# How to use log4j in REST Service

Tags: java, rest, log4j

I have tried using log4j in REST client and it logs the information. However, I have tried to log the events server side using log4j and it dose not record any logs. Here is my sample where I have used on my server side.

```
 @POST
    @Path("/send")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response consumeJSON(String str) throws Exception {
     AmazonKinesisRecordProducerSample.init();

     try {

            pushData(str);

            LOG.info(str)

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.info(""+e);
            return Response.status(400).entity(e).build();
        }

        return Response.status(200).entity(d).build();
    }
```

Here is my client code. This captures the logs.

```
public class JerseyClient {
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JerseyClient.class);
static Date date = new Date();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int i = 0;
        long createTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Server Response");
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Details d = new Details();
            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(
                JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
            WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("http://localhost:8080/JerseyJSON/rest/jsonServices/send");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, d);
            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
            }
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            LOG.info(output + "  inserted at-%d  " + createTime);
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This captures the log in TestLog.log under my project root directory. But, my server side code which is the `POST` method, this is running on the Tomcat is not capturing the logs.

Here is my log4j.xml for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Appenders -->

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="ROLL" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="Testlog.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2" />

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ} %-5r %-5p [%c{1}] (%t:%x) %m%n" />
    </layout>   
</appender>

<category name="com.java" additivity="false">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ROLL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</category>

<root>
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ROLL"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Which version of log4j are you using? 1.x or 2.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [the documentation on how to do an helloWorld](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html)

It seems you are mixing several Log package. Be sure to use Log4J and not the Java Logger. They have different syntax.

Then, in your code, I see several problems. In your try, you're calling for a new instance of Logger, `getLogger` is not a logging method. In your catch block, do not use `"" + e` to log your exception, use the library ability to log all the exception object including message and stackTrace.

EDIT:

Finally we found the answer. There is two project: client side with a main, and server side with REST service, with one log config for both. The problem was that the client side was logging in the local directory whereas the server side was logging in the Tomcat Directory.

Comment: I made that change. However, the client captures the logs and not the server side.

Comment: Can you reflect these changes on your question by adding a part EDIT pls. What do you mean by client capture the log but not the server side?

Comment: Maybe You've tested on other code but I don't see any logging in you client (the only one is commented). So you have one main app on client side and one REST Service on server side. Confirm that you have LOG calls AND config files in both client and server side.

Comment: I have commented it to test if server side is logging or not. I have both the client and server code in same package and same root folder. I have all log4j.xml in the root as well.

Comment: Maybe can you set debug mode and inspect the content of LOG in your client and in your server. If both are declared the same way and both have access to the config file I don't see why... Hey, maybe, where are you looking for your server log? in the Testlog.log? in your local project directory? If so then can you check in your Tomcat directory? As your server run in Tomcat and your file is in relative path it may be there. You can make the path Absolute (just for testing)

Comment: Yes, that did the trick for me. I have given the absolute path to point to Tomcat directory and it worked. Earlier, it was logging in the source dir. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are missing to include `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` in your classpath.

Comment: I have log4j.xml included. This is how I was able to capture the logs client side. But, when the war is deployed, I could not capture the logs in server side. The entire code is under one package. If the client does capture, the server also should be capturing. Which is not happening.

Comment: what type of server you are using when deploying? and please be more specific about client and server side. because the understanding for client side logging is not related to server side logging.

Answer (score 0):

Maven Dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Controller Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/userinfo")
public class UserController {


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    // get all userinfo
    @GetMapping(value = "/alluser", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<UserDto> getUserinfo() {
        LOGGER.info("inside class!!!! UserController, method!!!: getUserinfo");
        return userService.getAllUserInfo();
    }

    // get user info by id
    @GetMapping(value = "/{userId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public UserDto getUserById(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
        LOGGER.info("inside method!!!: getUserById", userId);
        return userService.getUserByUserId(userId);
    }
}
```

For all java code and reference use below link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4X99F6ckhw&t=4s